# convert MB to GB, is google unit converter wrong?

Tags: memory, byte, unit-conversion

I use google search engine for all my unit conversions, and now being working on some cloud pricing, I wanted to calculate how many GB would 250,000MB do, and type "kilobyte to byte" in google.

The problem I have is that the google tool gave me 250GB. Now I have always be told 1GB = 1024MB (and not exactly 1000), can someone confirm if I'm wrong ??

Actually, I was rather sure until now that was the base to convert Bytes, but having a hard time believing google would be mistaking (too much trust maybe?) I am in the search of expert opinion.

Of course, the EXACT figure is pretty important for cost projection...

Answer (score 8):

Following the SI standard, 1GB=1000MB and 1MB=1000kB. The units programmers usually call mega- and gigabytes should be called mebi- and gibibytes. See also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte

Many people keep using mega and giga incorrectly, both because of the long history, and because they don't like how "mebi" and "gibi" sound.

Comment: Thanks! I saw some article on that too, although as you may or may not know, the SI standard does not apply in the US... would you have an idea on that ?

Comment: The internet community is international, therefore international standards should be used on the internet. As for use in the USA, I'm not a US citizen, so I can't comment on what system they should use in their country.

Comment: In the same graph in the article, there is a column called memory, which is the context that programmers almost always refer to.

Answer (score -2):

1gb = 1024mb
Google uses the si conversion of 1gb= 1000mb
With that being said, the market uses the SI as a marketing tool only. What's being sold is for example 64.000 mb usb drive and sellers incorrectly market it as 64gb. If you devide that by 1024, you get 62,5gb which is the actual number of gbs that is displayed on "my computer"

Comment: Bill gates must know that better)